# Lightning record edit form is not navigating to record detail page after saving record

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, create-records, navigationmixin.navigate

I have `lightning-record-edit-form`  and I need to navigate to the record detail page after it is successfully created. I tried the below code and it is not working. What should I change here?

HTML Code:

```
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="MyCustomObject__c" record-id={recordId} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                <div class="slds-border_bottom">
    <lightning-layout >
                <lightning-layout-item size="6">
                    <div class="page-section page-header slds-text-heading_medium slds-border_right"></div>
                    <div class="page-section slds-border_right">
                        <lightning-layout size="12" multiple-rows="true">
    
                        <lightning-layout-item size="3">
                            <div class="page-section slds-border_bottom">
                                <lightning-input-field field-name="MyCustomField__c" variant="label-stacked"></lightning-input-field>
                            </div>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
   </lightning-layout >
   <lightning-button variant="brand" class="slds-align_absolute-center" label="Save" type="submit"></lightning-button>
   </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

JS Code:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
export default class MyCustomCmp extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
    
    @api recordId;
    myCustomObjectId;

    handleSuccess(e) {
        this.myCustomObjectId= e.detail.id;
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'My Custom Object Record Saved!',
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__recordPage",
            attributes: {
              objectApiName: "MyCustomObject__c",
              actionName: "view",
              recordId: "$myCustomObjectId"
            }
          });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass record id as

```
 this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__recordPage",
            attributes: {
              actionName: "view",
              recordId: this.myCustomObjectId
            }
          });
```